# Asignar valores a una variable static C++

Tags: c++, variables, clase, variables-globales, diseño-de-clases

Tengo la siguiente duda, ¿Es posible asignar diferentes valores a una variable static? Lo intentado hacer, pero se sobreescribe cuando creo diferentes objetos.

O sea yo se que una variable static está disponible para todos los objetos de una clase, por lo tanto cualquiera de ellos lo puede cambiar incluso sin crear un objeto en el main, si es erróneo lo que menciono me pueden corregir por favor. Sin embargo, mi interés es guardar un valor de cada uno los objetos que yo cree en una variable static.

Por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente código:

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include "Prueba.h"
    /* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
    system("pause") or input loop */
     using namespace std;

   int main() {

    Prueba A;
    A.guardar(23);
    cout << "A: " << A.getTipo ();

    Prueba B;
    B.guardar(26);
    cout << " B: " << B.getTipo () << "  ";

    cout << "A: " << A.getTipo (); //Debería ser 23 ?

}
```

Clase prueba:

```
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
#define PRUEBA_H

class Prueba
{
    public:
    static int tipo;
    Prueba ();
    ~Prueba ();
    void guardar (int copia_tipo);
    int getTipo ();
};

#endif
```

Implementación:

```
#include "Prueba.h"

int Prueba::tipo = 0;

Prueba::Prueba () 
{

}

Prueba::~Prueba ()
{

}

void Prueba::guardar(int copia_tipo)
{
    tipo = copia_tipo;
}

int Prueba::getTipo()
{
    return tipo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si he entendido lo que quieres, si lo he entendido puedes hacerlo con plantillas:

```
template <int tipo>
struct Prueba
{
    int getTipo () { return tipo; }
};
```

Esta aproximación te permite tener el mismo tipo para todas las instancias de `Prueba<X>` (siendo `X` un entero) pero NO te permite cambiar el valor durante la ejecución:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;

    Prueba<23> A;
    cout << "A: " << A.getTipo ();

    Prueba<26> B;
    cout << " B: " << B.getTipo () << "  ";

    cout << "A: " << A.getTipo (); // Es 23.

    return 0;
}
```

Siguiendo la premisa anterior, puedes guardar una variable estática de clase que pueda cambiar de valor:

```
template <int tipo_inicial>
struct Prueba
{
    static int tipo = tipo_inicial;
    void guardar (int copia_tipo) { tipo = copia_tipo; }
    int getTipo () { return tipo; }
};

int main() {
    using nasespace std;

    Prueba<23> A;
    cout << "A: " << A.getTipo (); // 23
    A.guardar(230);
    cout << "A: " << A.getTipo (); // 230

    Prueba<26> B;
    cout << "B: " << B.getTipo (); // 26
    B.guardar(260);
    cout << "B: " << B.getTipo (); // 260

    return 0;
}
```

Lo contraintuitvo de esta aproximación es que cada clase `Pureba<X>` es diferente de la clase `Prueba<Y>` y que una vez instanciada una clase `Prueba<X>` la `X` es invariable aunque el *tipo* haya cambiado:

```
int main() {
    using nasespace std;

    Prueba<23> A;
    cout << "A: " << A.getTipo (); // 23
    A.guardar(230);

    Prueba<23> AA = A;
    cout << "AA: " << AA.getTipo (); // 230

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**No** se puede.

Las variables `static` *pertenecen* a la clase; existe **1 única instancia** para todos los objetos de esa clase que crees.

Puedes verlas como si fueran variables en un namespace:

```
namespace Prueba {
  int tipo;
}
```

Es imposible crear varias *namespaces* con el mismo nombre; existe 1 y solo 1. Pues con las variables-miembro-staticas pasa igual: solo 1 por cada clase.

De hecho, si lo piensas bien, lo que tu pretendes hacer es crear una variable-miembro *corriente y moliente*: que pueda tener un valor distinto en cada instancia:

```
struct Prueba {
  int tipo;
}
```

Es más; si lo piensas un poco mas, verás que no tiene sentido lo que pretendes. Supongamos que **si fuera** posible asignar un valor distinto a múltiples instancias de una variable-miembro-estática: ¿ Como distinguirias una de otra ? Si para acceder a ellas se usa `Prueba::getTipo( )` ... ¿ Cómo escogerías **la instancia concreta** a la que pretendes acceder ? Solo puede existir **una y solo una** `class Prueba`.

Comment: Si, lo habia pensado, en tener una variable miembro corriente para cada objeto, pero el tema es que si recuerdas mi anterior post, en el main de referencia, hay una línea en el que hace una llamada a una variable static, creo que yo lo estoy entendiendo mal entonces, puedo poner esa parte aquí ? Disculpas por preguntar estas cosas raras :c

Comment: @CristhianIvan eso que comentas debería ser una pregunta totalmente nueva. No conviene mezclar temas porque entonces esto se convierte en un chat más que en un sitio de preguntas y respuestas

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Y lamento decirte que no es posible. `Pokemon::Aire` ... siempre va ser un único valor compartido por todos los `Pokemon`. ¿ Cual es el problema de usar una variable-miembro *normal y corriente* ? Si no quieres que se modifique, pues la declaras `const`.